# Lock access to a settings page

Tags: php, acl

I'm probably using the wrong search terms since I'm getting nowhere with google.

I have a site-wide settings page available only to admins. This question is not about permissions of users. How can I lock access to this page so that only a **single** admin can be using it at any one time?

My idea so far is to set a flag in the database, but how can I handle those instances where the admin closes the browser or otherwise leaves the page without releasing the lock?

Comment: you can use some `timestamp` like situation.

Comment: @StaticVariable You mean adding the `time()` to database rather than a simple boolean? Then later lookups can test for timeout. simple and elegant, I like it.

Answer (score 0):

There could be some workarounds for this but none of them is reliable.

As you said you need to set flags for the desired page on the database. You can disable the page view on every time if another admin is on the page (if flag is set).

To unset the flag, you need to use javascript. If user is leaving the page, you need to send an ajax request to some hidden URL on your script to unset the flag. I think that is the only way but It's not reliable. JS could be disabled on user's browser so you wouldn't know. To prevent this you can set a cronjob or add timestamp to database. If the flag is set more than 60 minutes, unset the flag.